# html / css: align texts when there is another element before texts

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I think this should be a simple html / css question, but I don't know how to put it in my words clearly. I am creating a responsive footer using React.js and I am not sure how to align texts when there is a icon before the texts. I am assuming that `**` is the icon.

```
   <span className="info_box">
    ** &nbsp; Room 1234, 12/F, Modern Warehouse, 10 Shing Yip Street, Kwun
    Tong, Kowloon, Hong Kong
  </span>
```

whenever I resize the window, the text aligns with the icon instead of texts. I've tried `display: wrap, inline, inline-block, flex` but they did not work out. Any helps would be appreciated. The link to the code down below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-kare-r9yfh8?file=/src/App.js:74-233

Comment: Can you put an image of what you are trying to do as a text display result ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with the **span** tag it doesn't allow manual styling fully. Instead use a **div** tag and apply styling on that tag(using className or id).

**js file**

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="info_box">
        ** &nbsp; Room 1234, 12/F, Modern Warehouse, 10 Shing Yip Street, Kwun
        Tong, Kowloon, Hong Kong
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

**css file**

```
.info_box {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**output is like this:**

[image]

Comment: I think this works for span as well, but the problem is, when I `text-align: left`, the next line of the text will be aligned with the icon instead of texts.

Comment: @Chocode then try adding different tags for both. That willl solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

```js
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <span className="info_box">
        <i>**</i>
        <p>Room 1234, 12/F, Modern Warehouse, 10 Shing Yip Street, Kwun Tong, Kowloon, Hong Kong</p>
      </span>
    </>
  );
}
```

**CSS**

```css
.info_box {display:flex;align-items:center;gap:8px;}
p {margin:0;padding:0;}
```

**Output**

[image]